# How to enable JPA facet in Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring, eclipse, jpa, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am using Sprint Tool Suite IDE.

> - Version: 3.8.4.RELEASE
> - Build Id: 201703310825
> - Platform: Eclipse Neon.3(4.6.3)

I am trying to do a spring boot demo application for reading and writing data into Postgres DB. As per Spring Boot Guides I was able to do so OK. I have the following dependencies in my Spring Boot project's pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now, I want to use [JPA Diagram Editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project_Tutorial) to do a visual design of my entities and generate domain entity code automatically. To do this, the tutorial says to enable JPA facet. When I am trying to do that in my project, I am getting an error "JPA 2.1 requires Java 1.5 or newer". I have Java 1.8 SDK only on my machine so that should not be an issue. I also went into the Runtimes tab to see if I can add something there, but there is nothing there.

So, how can I configure a Springboot project in STS to also be a JPA project so I can enable JPA related facet?

Comment: In `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler`, is JDK compliance level greater than 1.5?

Comment: Yes, it is set to 1.8 @kagmole.

Comment: Hmm so under `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` you only have a 1.8 JRE as default and when creating your JPA project you cannot change your `Target runtime`field with the 1.8 JRE?

Comment: I would not get your hopes up over the JPA Diagram Editor. It is half-baked and poorly maintained. :-(

Comment: I am trying out JPA Diagram Editor a go. It's buggy and sometimes crashes and I have to reboot STS IDE to get back working. Do you have any other recommendations for a designer that can generate JPA entity code, @BrianVosburgh? It need not integrate with the IDE... could be a standalone tool as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not know of any JPA tools like the Diagram Editor. The JPA spec is a bit complicated and does not map very cleanly to something visual. Have you seen what the JPA tools Eclipse plug-in (Dali, which is what the JPA Diagram Editor is part of and uses) does for you (via the JPA Structure and Details views and Problems/Warnings)? It is not a graphical representation, but it can be somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was missing. In the STS IDE, when I was trying to enable the **JPA** facet, I had only the **'Cloud Foundry Standalone Application'** checked. I guess Spring boot projects automatically have that facet enabled. Along with enabling the JPA facet, I had to enable the **Java** facet as well. I got JPA working and now I can use JPA Diagram editor.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions.